# GhostScipt - convert and resize image with gs

Tags: php, image, resize, ghostscript

I am using a ghost script to generate and convert images with the following command but i have to resize the image during the process.

My general command is

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=<out put file> -dJPEGQ=90 -r100 -q <input file> -c quit
```

I tried with some commands in gs site like

```
-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=w
-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=h
```

but with no luck!

Q: How do I resize the output file to a smaller size with fixed width of 100 px and free height ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do some PostScript programming, and the code would depend on whether you are reading PostScript or PDF as the input file.

Comment: you mean there isn't any specific device or switch for all image input files!?

Comment: Not for fixing one dimension while leaving the other free, no I don't believe so.